# How do I save current webpage state server side?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm looking to integrate a text editor into my html website. I already have a simple editor in JS but I have no way to save the changes back to the server. This is a bit above my expertise and I'm not having much luck finding a solution.

My goal is to have the entire html document, once modified in the browser, overwrite the original version on the server. 
So:

1. How would I grab the modified content from the browser?
2. How would I save that server-side?
3. Is there anything else I'm forgetting?

I'd like accomplish this using js (ajax and what not is ok too) & php exclusively. I'm open to any existing packages or software for this purpose as well (again using js & php).

Thanks!

Comment: something like tinymce? https://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: can we see some code? maybe the html structure or the script you are working on?

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
Scrapping html codes into string then save.

Comment: The basic idea is to put your text editor inside a `form` and then submit that form if you want to save. Do you PHP magic to save it into your data storage and then you're done.

Comment: @Luminous_Dev will that code grab the entire html document? If so how do you get that over to the php script?

Comment: That code will get the entire html code into a string format!  You can easily send string and save the string as it is!

Comment: @Luminous_Dev that did it, works perfectly, thanks!